# Delete matching line(s) from a list of files

Tags: bash, sed

I've just been writing some code, that renders a locale property redundant. Because of that, I'd like it to be able to remove that property from every locale file of the project, but I simply couldn't find a way of doing that, and I ended up doing it by hand in vim.

Now, I'm no UNIX black-belt, but I know that there must be a pretty simple solution to such a trivial problem, probably hidden in the depths of `sed` or `awk`. So I managed to match the property (the property being `no_outline`):

```
sed -e '/no_outline=/d' l10n/*/viewer.properties
```

But this only prints out the contents of each file, without the `no_outline` line. Isn't it possible to write the "result" of the `sed` command to the same file as it was executed on?

Comment: what OS are you running under?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could:

```
sed -i '/no_outline=/d' l10n/*/viewer.properties
```

from man page:

```
   -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

              edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```

Comment: I'm on a Mac OSX machine, which meant that I needed to write `LANG=C sed -i '' -e '/no_outline=.*/d' l10n/*/viewer.properties` (The LANG part, because of some "illegal byte sequence"), but thanks for showing me the `-i` option